# Spring annotation with dynamic argument

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations

```
@ColumnTransformer(read = "aes_decrypt(card_no_encrypt, '${encryption.key}')", write = "aes_encrypt(?,'${encryption.key}')")
    public String cardNoEncrypt;
```

I need to get pass the encryption key from properties file. But this implementation takes '${encryption.key}' itself as the key, not the value of it.

Comment: Hibernate knows nothing about spring's property resolving. It does not work this way.

Comment: As a workaround I would suggest to implement `org.hibernate.Interceptor` (that is an interface) or even `org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor` (that is an abstract class and requires less code for overriding): just override methods `onLoad` and `onSave`.

Comment: Any updates on this?